# Need help figuring out MySQL query to count if a certain number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have a table setup like this:

```
fruit1 | fruit2 | fruit3 | fruit4 | number1 | number2 | number3 | number4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
apple  | orange | banana |  berry |    5    |    2    |    1    |    4   
orange | banana | apple  |  berry |    3    |    2    |    5    |    2
berry  | banana | orange |  apple |    1    |    2    |    5    |    2
```

I need a MySQL query to count how many times a given fruit is number 5.  In this example, apple is 5 twice and orange is 5 once.  Does that make sense?  fruit1's number is number1, fruit2's number is number2, etc...

I could do this with a bit of php code but I know it's a pretty simple MySQL query.  I just have the hardest time putting queries together.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're having a hard time because your table is not normalized properly.

Comment: 0_o (I agree with Jack, odd schema indeed!)

Comment: If you have to number your columns like that, you are doing something wrong.  It's like if you have variables in your program named `$thing1`, `$thing2`, `$thing3`, they should be in an array called `$things`.  In this case, because you have a set of columns named fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, then you should have a subtable of fruits.

Comment: I'm curious how you guys think I should be organizing my DB differently. I have a form where a user will select up to 5 fruits from a dropdown and then rate each fruit from 1 to 5. The selections and ratings are then written to the table as 1 record.  All of the fruits will be unique. Are you guys saying I should have two different tables with a shared column between them like date/time or something?  One fruit table and one number table? I'm not sure how that would make things easier so I'm probably not understanding what you are suggesting.  Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Have a table with columns `formid`, `fruit`, and `rating`, with `formid` and `fruit` as the primary key. Each fruit the user selects will be a different row in this table, with `formid` representing that user's form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT fruit, COUNT(*) NumberOfInstance
FROM
(
    SELECT fruit1 fruit, number1 num FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fruit2 fruit, number2 num FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fruit3 fruit, number3 num FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT fruit4 fruit, number4 num FROM table1
) s
WHERE num = 5
GROUP BY fruit
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fa84/3)

Comment: This worked perfect, thanks!  I guess I need to work on my table organization though.  I appreciate the quick help.

Comment: So I've been trying to figure out how to modify the query to show all the numbers for each fruit.  So I'd get a table that shows:
Fruit | 5's | 4's | 3's | 2's | 1's
Apple | 2   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0  
Banana| 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1  
...

Is this a simple addition to the query?  Or does this make it way more complicated?

Comment: I tried that and it's not giving me what I'd expect.  If I remove "Where num = 5" I still just get two columns.  In the example, all fruits have the number 3.

Comment: @JackHillard yes because as you can see, there are only two columns returned by the subquery. It is much better to open a new question regarding the changes.