# Another issue with my badly organized table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, pivot

I have a table setup like this:

```
fruit1 | fruit2 | fruit3 | fruit4 | number1 | number2 | number3 | number4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
apple  | orange | banana |  berry |    5    |    2    |    1    |    4   
orange | banana | apple  |  berry |    3    |    2    |    5    |    2
berry  | banana | orange |  apple |    1    |    2    |    5    |    2
```

I need a MySQL query to count how many times each fruit is each number. So, it would end up something like this:

```
Fruit | 5's | 4's | 3's | 2's | 1's 
-----------------------------------
Apple | 2   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0 
Banana| 0   | 0   | 1   | 1   | 1
...
```

JW has helped me out a lot but I can't figure out how to go from JW's solution to what I need now.
[Need help figuring out MySQL query to count if a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088443/need-help-figuring-out-mysql-query-to-count-if-a-certain-number)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Yes, I understand it's not a well created table (as I stated in the title).  Correcting the table would require more work in the rest of the php pages than it's worth since what I need should be able to be done with a single query (I assume).  I've gotten good suggestions in the other thread that I'll be able to use next time I have a similar table.

Comment: Data in columns `number1,...` can be maximum 5?

Comment: Yes, they are a max value of 5.  Though, I could have more than just 4 fruits and 4 numbers but I think I could figure that out if I got the basics for the 4 fruits.

Comment: banana doesn't have `1` for `3's`, it should have `2` for `2's` and `1` for `1's`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have mentioned in your comment that the *maximum value is 5*, so here's a pivoted version using `case` from your previous question which you want it here,

```
SELECT fruit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN num = 5 THEN NumberOfInstance ELSE 0 END) `5's`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN num = 4 THEN NumberOfInstance ELSE 0 END) `4's`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN num = 3 THEN NumberOfInstance ELSE 0 END) `3's`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN num = 2 THEN NumberOfInstance ELSE 0 END) `2's`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN num = 1 THEN NumberOfInstance ELSE 0 END) `1's`
FROM
      (
        SELECT fruit, num, COUNT(*) NumberOfInstance
        FROM 
        (
          SELECT fruit1 fruit, number1 num FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT fruit2 fruit, number2 num FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT fruit3 fruit, number3 num FROM table1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT fruit4 fruit, number4 num FROM table1
        ) s 
        GROUP BY fruit, num
      ) s
GROUP BY fruit;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fa84/19)

Comment: +1 : Nice solution. I would say **this is best example where we can say, HOW NICE LOOKING query has become SO UGLY just because of BAD DB structure**

Comment: Haha, wow people really hate my table structure.  
JW, you're a wizard.  Solution worked perfect.  Once again, I appreciate it!